# How to access global instance variable from another instance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

I'm new to Ruby and I'm trying to change some of my code to have OO design using our current framework. When converting my utility file to classes I encountered the following problem:

There are two functions *create_output_file* and *write_to* are framework methods (**don't belong to any classes**) that I cannot touch (They specifies where to write to the framework). 
And there is a class A I wrote which needs to use the *write_to* to log the time and return status of the *foo()*.

```
<!-- language: lang-rb -->
def create_output_file(params)
  @output_file = params["SS_output_file"]
  @hand = File.open(@output_file, "a")
  write_to "New Run - Shell Cmd\n\n"
  return true
end
def write_to(message, newline = true)
  return if message.nil?
  sep = newline ? "\n" : ""
  @hand.print(message + sep)
  print(message + sep)
end

def this_is_dum
  print("This is to show class A have access to global methods.\n")
end

class A
  def foo()
    # Do something that needs the status of instance A
    this_is_dum()
    write_to("This is the current status!")
  end

end

# Main routine
params = {}
params["SS_output_file"] = "./debugging_log"
create_output_file(params)  #sets the @hand file handle
A.new.foo
```

These are the outputs I'm getting:

> New Run - Shell Cmd:
>
> This is to show class A have access to global methods.
>   D:/data/weshi/workspace/RubyBRPM2/scripts/Random.rb:12:in `write_to':
>   private method `print' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>     from D:/data/weshi/workspace/RubyBRPM2/scripts/Random.rb:18:in
>   `foo'
>    from
>   D:/data/weshi/workspace/RubyBRPM2/scripts/Random.rb:26:in
>   `'

After digging a bit I found that `@hand` was not accessed during the `foo()` scope. 
I'm not sure how I'll be able to access the `@hand` variable inside class A and what it means without assigning to a class. But I do need the `write_to` function to work in accordance to the whole framework. Any suggestions or instructions are welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `@hand` to your `A` instance in the constructor like that:

```
def create_output_file(params)
  @output_file = params["SS_output_file"]
  @hand = File.open(@output_file, "a")
  write_to "New Run - Shell Cmd\n\n"
  return true
end
def write_to(message, newline = true)
  return if message.nil?
  sep = newline ? "\n" : ""
  @hand.print(message + sep)
  print(message + sep)
end

def this_is_dum
  print("This is to show class A have access to global methods.\n")
end

class A
  def initialize(hand)
    @hand = hand
  end

  def foo()
    # Do something that needs the status of instance A
    this_is_dum()
    write_to("This is the current status!")
  end

end

# Main routine
params = {}
params["SS_output_file"] = "./debugging_log"
create_output_file(params)  #sets the @hand file handle
A.new(@hand).foo
```

The output is:

```
New Run - Shell Cmd

This is to show class A have access to global methods.
This is the current status!
```

Otherwise I found [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215216/inherit-one-instance-variable-from-the-global-scope) which may be a little bit more complicated.